# after restarting terminal, the old ruby version set up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I installed ruby version to my computer 2.1.5, but I have to set up each time with the commands, (eval "$(rbenv init -)) each time I restart the terminal on my mac(system version set back). I set up the system with rbenv and try to use the global command also, but did not work.

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I set up the system with rbenv"? Did you follow the installation instructions and add `eval "$(rbenv init -)` to your startup script? What do you mean by "try to use the global command also, but did not work"? What does "try" mean? Did you or did you not use the `rvm global` command? And exactly *how* did it "not work"?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.ruby-version` file in root of your project

```
#.ruby-version
2.1.5
```

This will select the mentioned ruby version automatically

Or simply add the following in `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.5'
.
.
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds you have to edit .profle or .bash ... or whatever file that uses OSx to initialize the environment in terminal.

I recommend you use [RVM](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics)

It will solve this and other possible issues